# Typeorm Postgres Migration not running

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I having a problem with the migration of my back end. It was working. I run on my windows 10 PRO the docker with the database. follow below the link of my code.

https://github.com/fabioniglio/project-gobarber-Backend

When I execute the yarn typeorm migration:run is suppose to run all the migrations but instead is doing nothing and doesn't give any error.

Follow below the configuration of my docker-compose and ormconfig.

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3.7"

services:
  postgres:
    networks:
      - test
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: gostack_gobarber
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
    container_name: gostack_gobarber
  mongodb:
    networks:
      - test
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    container_name: mongodb
  redis:
    networks:
      - test
    image: redis:alpine
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    container_name: redis
networks:
  test:
    external:
      name: nat
```

ormconfig.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "default",
    "type": "postgres",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "docker",
    "database": "gostack_gobarber",
    "entities": ["./src/modules/**/infra/typeorm/entities/*.ts"],
    "migrations": ["./src/shared/infra/typeorm/migrations/*.ts"],
    "cli": {
      "migrationsDir": "./src/shared/infra/typeorm/migrations"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "mongo",
    "type": "mongodb",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 27017,
    "database": "gobarber",
    "useUnifiedTopology": true,
    "entities": ["./src/modules/**/infra/typeorm/schemas/*.ts"]
  }
]
```

Running the migration

```
C:\Users\Fabio Niglio\Documents\projects\bootcamp\Modulo5\primeiro-projeto-node>yarn typeorm migration:run
yarn run v1.22.0
$ ts-node-dev -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run
Using ts-node version 8.8.2, typescript version 3.8.3
Done in 1.87s.
```